# In react hook state is not retaining its previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components. The parent component calls an api, sets the state and sends this data to child component. If the child component triggers an event then parent component once again makes an api call and set the new data with previous data.

But the state is not retaining its previous state. When I come back to parent component instead new data will be added.

For instance: 1st time userData has 10 array of objects. I'll send this to child. When I trigger event in child, parent component makes an api call and will send another array of 10 objects. Total will be 20 records. (its setting correctly and sending this to child).

For 3rd api call, original array in parent has only 10 records plus new api call data (total 20). Now it should be 20+10=30 records but its has only 20. Why is this happening?

Parent component:

```
const onBottomEventSeeAlluser = async () => {
    Pagination.offset = Pagination.offset + 1;
    await HomeAPI.newsDetail(Pagination.offset, Pagination.limit).then(
      userData=> {
        console.log(userData.data, loading);
        setUserData(userPData=>([...userPData, ...userData.data]));      
      }
    );
  };
render (
 <AllUser userDataNews={userData}  onBottomEvent={onBottomEventSeeAllUser} ></AllUser>
)
```

Child component:

```
function AllUser({ userDataNews, onBottomEvent }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(userDataNews);
    console.log(BottomScrollListener.defaultProps);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScrollCheck, true);
  }, []);
  const onScrollCheck = event => {
    event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop ===
    event.target.clientHeight
      ? onBottomEvent()
      : "";
  };
}
```

Comment: `useEffect` is not for saving in state, u need `useState` hook

Comment: Code basically [works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-cookies-fsf93) so the issue has to be elsewhere.

Comment: Show the console logs?

Comment: it worked for me .I used  setGameNewsData(gameNewsData => gameNewsData.concat(gameData.data));

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is not for saving in state, u need `useState` hook

> Sample code:

```
function AllUser({ userDataNews, onBottomEvent }) {
  const [userNews, setUserDataNews] = useSate(userDataNews)
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(userNews);
    console.log(BottomScrollListener.defaultProps);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScrollCheck, true);
  }, []);
  const onScrollCheck = event => {
    event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop ===
    event.target.clientHeight
      ? onBottomEvent()
      : "";
  };
  const update = async () => {
    const data = await someAPI()
    setUserDataNews(userDataNews.concat(data))
  }
}
```